# Resize icon in Floatingactionbutton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

hey guys im using this library https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton then my problem is my icon in floatingactionbutton is not fit. The size of my icon is 60dp and i want it to resize it programmatically, so it can fit. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"   //your Icon
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true" />  //add this
```

Now in res/values/dimens.xml: override the attribute.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This line is important `<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>` . Change it according to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parameters of `setSize()` for FloatingActionBution. Use the below code in your activity Java file:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_AUTO);
```

All three parameters are: `.SIZE_AUTO`, `.SIZE_MINI`, `.SIZE_NORMAL`